# HiveQL and rank()

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I can't understand HiveQL rank(). I've found a couple of implementations of rank UDF's on the WWW, such as [Edward's nice example](http://www.edwardcapriolo.com/roller/edwardcapriolo/entry/doing_rank_with_hive). I can load and access the functions, but I can't get them to do what I want. Here is a detailed example:

Loading the UDF into the CLI process:

```
$ javac -classpath /home/hadoop/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar:/home/hadoop/hive/lib/hive-exec-0.10.0.jar com/m6d/hiveudf/Rank2.java 
$ jar -cvf Rank2.jar com/m6d/hiveudf/Rank2.class
hive> ADD JAR /home/hadoop/MyDemo/Rank2.jar;
hive> CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION Rank2 AS 'com.m6d.hiveudf.Rank2';
```

Create a table:

```
create table purchases (
  SalesRepId String, 
  PurchaseOrderId INT, 
  Amount INT
) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Load data from this CSV:

```
Jana,1,100
Nadia,2,200
Nadia,3,600
Daniel,4,80
Jana,5,120
William,6,170
Daniel,7,140
```

With this from the CLI:

```
LOAD DATA 
  LOCAL INPATH '/home/hadoop/MyDemo/purchases.csv'
  INTO TABLE purchases;
```

Now I can see my top Sales Reps:

```
select SalesRepId,sum(amount) as volume
from purchases
group by SalesRepId
ORDER BY volume DESC;
```

Nadia has sold $800 of stuff, Daniel and Jana have both sold $220, and William has sold $170

```
SalesRep    Amount
--------    ------
Nadia       800
Daniel      220
Jana        220
William     170
```

Now all I want to do is number them: Nadia is #1, Daniel and Jana are tied for #2, and William is #4 (not #3)

```
select SalesRepId, V.volume,rank2(V.volume)
from 
(select SalesRepId,sum(amount) as volume
from purchases
group by SalesRepId
ORDER BY volume DESC) V;
```

This is what I get, but NOT what I want:

```
SalesRep   Amount  Rank
--------   ------  ----
Nadia       800      1
Daniel      220      1
Jana        220      2
William     170      1
```

This is what I WANT, but I can't make hive do it for me:

```
SalesRep   Amount  Rank
--------   ------  ----
Nadia       800      1
Daniel      220      2
Jana        220      2
William     170      4
```

Can you help me with the correct HiveQL to rank my Sales Reps?

Thanks to JtheRocker for his response. His change resulted in this list:

```
SalesRep   Amount  Rank
--------   ------  ----
William     170     1
Daniel      220     2
Jana        220     2
Nadia       800     3
```

A slight modification to show Nadia as 4th (not 3rd):

```
private row_number;
@Override
public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] currentKey) throws HiveException {
  row_number++;
  if (!sameAsPreviousKey(currentKey)) {
    this.counter = row_number;
    copyToPreviousKey(currentKey);
  }
return new Long(this.counter);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the [Windowing and Analytics functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) introduced in Hive 0.11, you can use:

```
select SalesRepId, volume as amount , rank() over (order by V.volume desc) as rank from 
(select SalesRepId,sum(amount) as volume from purchases group by SalesRepId) V;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a evaluate function as below, assuming you are using the function directly form the guide you mentioned,

```
private long counter;
@Override
  public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] currentKey) throws HiveException {
    if (!sameAsPreviousKey(currentKey)) {
      this.counter = 0;
      copyToPreviousKey(currentKey);
    }

    return new Long(++this.counter);
  }
```

try changing it to the following, so that the counter is not reset when it finds a new volume, rather you don't increment if you find the same volume but increment only when it finds a new volume.

```
private long counter;
@Override
  public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] currentKey) throws HiveException {
    //when not same as previous key you rather increment
    if (!sameAsPreviousKey(currentKey)) {
      this.counter ++;
      copyToPreviousKey(currentKey);
    }
    //else you keep the counter as it is
    return new Long(++this.counter);
 }
```

Tell me if this helps.

Comment: Thanks to JtheRocker for his response. His change resulted in ranking similar to Oracle DENSE_RANK. See the modification above to make this Hive UDF evaluate in a manner similar to Oracle RANK.

Comment: I didn't pay good attention to the order '1,2,2,4' when I posted the answer and thought you wanted to do this 1,2,2,3 instead :). Thank a lot for correcting me and glad that it helped you find the solution you wanted. :)