# Finding rank in hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have a set of data

```
alex, 50
anu, 85
limi, 41
sam, 56
```

I need to find the rank of the students and store it in another column with the rank
eg:-

```
alex    50 3
anu     85 1
limi    41 4
sam     56 2
```

I tried with the rank function.

```
SELECT
  a.name, a.mark,
rank() over (ORDER BY a.mark DESC) as rank
FROM
  list a;
```

Comment: MySQL or Hive? the answers will differ *a lot*.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu  hive only

Comment: Will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156105/hiveql-and-rank/18159383#18159383

Comment: select name, mark , rank() over (order by mark) as rank from list;   ............

this is not working

anything wrong with the query ?

Answer (score 1):

About Window and Analytic functions in HIVE. They were introduced in HIVE 0.11, see [HIVE-896](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-896). You can read the specification in the [Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics#LanguageManualWindowingAndAnalytics-WindowingandAnalyticsFunctions), including examples.

Make sure you run on Hive 0.11 to start with.

Comment: i am sorry for that. am new to the programming side.. its actually showing a syntax error.

FAILED: ParseException line 1:25 missing FROM at '(' near '(' in subquery source
line 1:26 cannot recognize input near ')' '(' 'over' in subquery source

Comment: i have tried the same query with different data.. all are showing the same error.. please help me.

Comment: Do you know what Hive version are you running?

Comment: am using hive 0.10 only